# How to add a dropshadow to a navigation bar when the user starts to scroll?

Tags: jquery, css

Do you think it's possible to use CSS3 for this kind of effect? I am trying to achieve something like this for my navigation bar. http://garypeppergirl.com/ You can see that the style of the navigation changes when a user scrolls down? With sample website, the height changes... I want mine to have a dropshadow D: If CSS3 can't do it... do you guys know how to achieve it using Javascript or Jquery? Someone please help me.  Thank you!

Comment: You can't target scroll events with CSS but you can with jQuery. Get started with that and post your code of what you've tried then we can help you.

Answer (score 4):

You can use jQuery's `scrollTop()` method to determine your scrolled distance:

```
var distance  = $(window).scrollTop();
```

You can then use it in conjunction with the `.scroll()` event and add classes to your nav. You can then style the new class with the `box-shadow` property:

```
var nav = $('#nav'); // Change to nav div
var nav_class = 'mini-nav'; // Change to class name
var threshold = 100; // Change to pixels scrolled

$(window).scroll(function () {
    var distance = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (distance > threshold) { // If scrolled past threshold
        nav.addClass(nav_class); // Add class to nav
    } else { // If user scrolls back to top
        if (nav.hasClass(nav_class)) { // And if class has been added
            nav.removeClass(nav_class); // Remove it
        }
    }
});
```

Here is a fiddle to get you started:

http://jsfiddle.net/X967T/5/

Comment: Nice solution. The only niggle I have is `$class` and `$threshold` aren't jQuery objects so shouldn't really have a `$` prefix